# How to send value from dropdown list?

Tags: angularjs

I have dropdown list :

```
<select name="timefilter" id="timefilter">
 <option value="Last week">@Translate("LAST_WEEK")</option>
<option value="Last 3 days">@Translate("LAST_3_DAYS")</option>
 <option value="Yesterday">@Translate("YESTERDAY")</option>
<option value="Today">Translate("TODAY")</option>
</select>
```

I need to send value from dropdown list to `$scope`

```
  $scope.GetMenuForSelectedTime = function (numberOfDays) {
}
```

How can i do it?

EDIT: My function that i need to call:

```
   $scope.SelectTicketByTime = function (range) {

    var range = range;
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getUTCDate().padLeft();
    var monthIndex = (date.getUTCMonth() + 1).padLeft();
    var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var hours = date.getUTCHours().padLeft();
    var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes().padLeft();


    $scope.GetMenuForSelectedTime = function (numberOfDays) {


        var d = new Date();
        d.toUTCString();
        day = date.getUTCDate() - numberOfDays;
        day = day.padLeft();
        var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
        d.setHours(00);
        var hoursToAdd = offset / 60;
        d.setHours(hoursToAdd);

        if (day > daysInMonth(monthIndex, year)) {
            var dayOffset = day - daysInMonth(monthIndex, year);
            day = dayOffset.padLeft();

            monthIndex = (date.getUTCMonth() + 2).padLeft();
        }
        var To = year + monthIndex + day + d.getHours() + '00';

        $scope.to = To;

        $http.get(TicketUrl + 'GetTickets/0/0?DateFrom=' + $scope.from + '&DateTo=' + $scope.to).
        then(RecivedTickets, ErrorResponse);
    }





    if (range == "Today") {
        $scope.GetMenuForSelectedTime(0);
    }

    else if (range == "Yesterday") {
        $scope.GetMenuForSelectedTime(1);
    }
    else if (width == "Last 3 days") {
        $scope.GetMenuForSelectedTime(3);

    }  else if (width == "Last 7 days") {
        $scope.GetMenuForSelectedTime(7);

    }
```

Comment: Add `ng-model` to your select?

Comment: can u put an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the example for putvande response (thanks to him):

```
<select name="timefilter" id="timefilter" ng-model="selectedTime">
 <option value="Last week">@Translate("LAST_WEEK")</option>
<option value="Last 3 days">@Translate("LAST_3_DAYS")</option>
 <option value="Yesterday">@Translate("YESTERDAY")</option>
<option value="Today">Translate("TODAY")</option>
</select>
```

And then you will have the value of your option in the controller :

```
$scope.selectedTime //The selected option
```

**Edit :** The function in your controller, will not need a value in param because the controller already know this value. You should have something like this.

```
$scope.SelectTicketByTime = function () {
    var range = $scope.selectedTime;
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getUTCDate().padLeft();
    var monthIndex = (date.getUTCMonth() + 1).padLeft();
    var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var hours = date.getUTCHours().padLeft();
    var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes().padLeft();
}
```

Comment: When i change dropdown list nothing happend...i dont get any call

Comment: Did you try to print "selectedTime" ? What's his value ?

Comment: nothing...its not calling my function at all...i have function   $scope.SelectTicketByTime = function (range) {
        } in controller where range is value from dropdown list

Comment: @None So do I to show how it works in your function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80176/discussion-between-none-and-apedemak).

Answer (score 0):

I modify the code with `ng-options` and when you change any option in the dropdown, the `ng-change` will fire

```
<select name="ruleDetails" ng-model="selectedTime" 
  ng-options="time.id as time.value for time in timeDetails" 
  ng-change="GetMenuForSelectedTime(selectedTime)">
  <option value="">-Select Time-</option>
</select>

$scope.GetMenuForSelectedTime = function(id) {
    alert(id);
};
```

**UPDATE:**

This code also works, `value` will pass to the function.

```
<select name="timefilter" id="timefilter" 
  ng-model="selectedTime" 
  ng-change="GetMenuForSelectedTime(selectedTime)">
  <option value="Last week">@Translate("LAST_WEEK")</option>
  <option value="Last 3 days">@Translate("LAST_3_DAYS")</option>
  <option value="Yesterday">@Translate("YESTERDAY")</option>
  <option value="Today">Translate("TODAY")</option>
</select>
```

Please check this [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/tXRz1L5ywlOCJF7KfwaZ?p=preview)

Comment: its good example just problem is that i need this dropdown list in mvc populated because im using @Translate function if u now what i mean?

Comment: The problem here is that the function `getMenuForSelectedTime` expect an number of day (int) and the value of the select are string.